# need to print a sequence of numbers on excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet and I resized the print area to print on A5 size.
Now I have 2 cells that fit in the "A5" paper and each one has a number.

What I need is to print numbers from (1 to 5000) with one click (each A5 paper should have two numbers).

For example

```
paper 1 have: 1 and 2
paper 2 have: 3 and 4
paper 3 have: 5 and 6
etc..
```

Also can I put a logo above each number? Can anyone help me?

Comment: @MuhammadSEltyar Welcome to Superuser. Are you looking for a (VBA) script that automatically generates a file with the numbers and logos and sets the print options properly?

Comment: Your number should be in one column or one row and the logo above each one or in header

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Karlo yes that's what i need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a logo above each number you may want to consider using a single number per page and put the logo in the page header.

Most printers can print 2, 4 or 8 pages on one sheet of paper.

Create a list of 5000 numbers with the Fill command. Size the Excel cells to fit one A4 page by using an absurdly big font size, add a header with the logo, then use the printer settings to print several pages on one sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1):

You can write 1 in A1, go to A5000 and write 1, go to A1 and **Ctrl + C** to copy, move to A2 press **Ctrl+Shift+End** then **Enter** it will copy 1 to all A2:A5000 now write 2 in A2 and select A1 and A2 put the pointer at the right down corner of A2 and double click it will fill the column 1, 2, 3...5000.
To change it to Row select it, copy and paste special in B1 Transpose then delete column A you will have the numbers in Row 1.
Another way with Fill series, write 1 in A1 select it click Fill in **Edit Group choose Series Rows, Linear, Step Value 1 stop value 5000** you will have your numbers in Row 1 or **Columns** instead of Rows **after Series**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a must, but I would suggest you to use Word's Mail Merge functionality for this. Excel does not seem to be the best place to handle this type op printing operations.

You can take look at Microsoft site:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294683

Comment: How exactly would you use Mail merge for this?

Comment: You can create a A5 sized Word document. In the document you can add a logo and a placeholder for the number.

Then create an excel sheet with number 1 to 5000.

Using the mail merge wizard in Word, use the Excel file as data source and perform the merge. Now you have 5000 pages each with a number and logo.

You can print them in A4 size, 2 pages per sheet to have the print outs.

Antoher reference maybe:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Word-mail-merge-A-walk-through-the-process-4ad61088-e108-4f56-b60d-e3c7d30c954a

Comment: That is probably the approach with the most control over the output.

Comment: Hi Atlas - good answer. To make it more helpful for visitors could you edit your answer to include the explanation you've added in the comments? Many readers will blow past the comments without reading them.